# What should the template be for a certain view and model . And what should be in the urls.py?

Tags: django

I am very new to Django , and learning it through a lot of trial and error process . Mostly errors .

This is what my view looks like 
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

```
def login(request):
    def errorHandle(error):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('login.html', {
                'error' : error,
                'form' : form,
        })
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = LoginForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    # Redirect to a success page.
                    login(request, user)
                    return render_to_response('userprof/login.html', {
                        'username': username,
                    })
                else:
                    # Return a 'disabled account' error message
                    error = u'account disabled'
                    return errorHandle(error)
            else:
                 # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
                error = u'invalid login'
                return errorHandle(error)
        else:
            error = u'form is invalid'
            return errorHandle(error)
    else:
        form = LoginForm() # An unbound form
        return render_to_response('login.html', {
            'form': form,
        })
```

This is my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    #other fields here

    def __str__(self):  
          return "%s's profile" % self.user  

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)  

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

What should be my template that must have a username and password field  to send the value to this view . 
I am very confused with the using of django user widget way of doing it , thus these doubts .

Another thing would be , what should be in my urls.py ? 
Ps: I am getting a reverse error as of now .

Answer (score 0):

Django already has a built-in view for it - `django.contrib.auth.views.login` (which is highly customizable). [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) will provide with you with sample template and url pattern.

Comment: I am extremely confused in that documentation . Thus came here .

Comment: @mekasperasky What exactly confuses you? What task you can't perform?

Comment: I can get my login template / view / models up . The problem comes when I deal with urls .

Comment: @mekasperasky Import it to your `urls.py`: `from views import login`. Then add the following pattern: `url(r'^login/$', login, name='login')`
`

Comment: @mekasperasky BTW, have you walked through [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/)? It's a very good starting point to avoid a lot a errors.

Comment: Yes . I have done that . Once I log in , this is the error I get . -> The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these. Though no where in my ursl.py I have mentioned about accounts/profile .

Comment: @mekasperasky Set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py` to url you want user to be redirected after login.

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'url(r'^userprof/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.loggedin', {'template_name': 'userprof/loggedin.html'}),' This is what I did and it gave error

Comment: Did that . Put "loggedin.html" in the userprof templates . Wrote a class in the views.py still get an error saying template does not exist

Comment: I also have a doubt . In my view , I have stated that if login is success it should be redirected to loggedin.html . Shouldn't that be enough ?

Comment: @mekasperasky I see no redirects in your view. Anyway you can't redirect to template, you redirect to url. If it says template does not exist, it also says what template doesn't exist. Create it.

Comment: I have already created a template loggedin.html inside templates/userprof . Still no success .

Comment: url(r'^userprof/$', 'userprof.views.loggedin',name='loggedin'), This is what I have done in views.py

Comment: @mekasperasky Are you sure you've done tutorial? We can spend a lot of time here, but it will be more productively for you to learn some basic things first.